# Image not fit to imageview in custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm trying to load a image to my tableview cell, however, the image seems to be bigger than the imageview and exceed the boundary of imageview. 
I tried to set the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView` to `ScaleAspectFit` but it didn't solve my problem.

**Code :**

```
cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
switch (post.priorityLevel){
    case "High Priority Posting":
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "High Priority Posting")
    case "Priority Posting":
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Priority Posting")
    case "General Posting":
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "General Posting")
    default:
        print("Priority Level can't be loaded to table")
}
```

I added screenshots of my table view from Interface builder and the result on simulator.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can check image size in UI debugging and also check all constraints. If you could show us which constraints have you set for cell, then we can surely help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow below constraint and you will see the magic of Auto layouts

ImageView constraints:

[image]

Set the fix height and width you want to display for the imageView, and set VerticalCentre constraint. Set imageView's content mode to Aspect Fit.

Top label constraints:

[image]

Label TrailingSpace constraint should not be a constant value, instead set it to standard spacing (i.e 8 pts).

Second label constraints:

[image]

Labels TrailingSpace and BottomSpace constraint should not be a constant value, instead set it to standard spacing (i.e 8 pts), and set its VerticalContentHugging priority to 250

[image]

Update:

ImageView vertical constraint to cell:

[image]

Label1 TrailingSpace to cell with standard spacing:

[image]

Label2 TrailingSpace to cell with standard spacing and BottomSpace to cell with standard spacing.

[image]

Comment: Hi bharat, i love your answer, but can you tell me where to add verticalCentre constraint and  Label trailing space pls? Couldn't find them anywhere

Comment: Thank you so much for your update!!,This is probably the best answer i've ever received on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Try cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

Comment: So may be problem in your designing.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1

In this official tutorial, they design a tableview exactly like yours. I think your main issue has to do with the lack of constraints/autolayout

Comment: Yes, this is the exact tut i followed, i followed almost every step, but they didn't mention constraint or autolayout in the tut

Answer (score 0):

UIImage

1) first you set the imageview leading space ,equal height,center vertically to container 
2)set height itself

City and State

1) set horizontal space and Top to UiimageView, Trailing space to   container view
  2)set height itself

Description label

1)set horizontal space and Bottom to UiimageView, Trailing space to container view

2)set height itself
story board -> set lines = 0

Answer (score 0):

If its a custom table view cell, dont name the imageView outlet to "imageView", name it to any other for eg: "cellImageView". and then try setting clipsToBound to true of your cell cellImageView.